# Read Fortnite Json API

Tags: java, json, gson

So I'm trying to read a JSON file in from a website ([fortniteapi.com](https://fortniteapi.com/)), every time I try to download the file to my local computer it does not download. I've been at this for about a week and I just can't figure out why it won't work.

also i'm using **Gson**

**Here is my code so far:**

```
package sample;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Fortnite");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
    ReadJson();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void  ReadJson()
{
    try {
        // read url
        String sURL = "https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/id?username=Ninja"; //just a string
        // Connect to the URL using java's native library
        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        // Convert to a JSON object
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
        String output = rootobj.get("username").getAsString(); //just grab the username value

        // print out the result/output
        System.out.println(output);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unexpected Error.");
       // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oh no something went wrong.", "Unexpected Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  What are they?

Comment: I would start with printing the exception using `e.printStackTrace();` instead of printing `Unexpected Error.`. Once that's done you can see it returns 403

Comment: Yeah, the error is "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/id?username=Ninja".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The error

After reading the `errorStream()` of the `request` (after casting it to `HttpURLConnection`) HTML is printed and states:

> Access denied | fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com used Cloudflare
>   to restrict access

and

> The owner of this website (fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com) has
>   banned your access based on your browser's signature
>   (mybrowsersignature).

### What does this mean

Cloudflare states that [that error](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171806-Error-1010-The-owner-of-this-website-has-banned-your-access-based-on-your-browser-s-signature) means that:

> the domain owner is blocking this request based on the client's web
>   browser signature.

and that the feature is called "Browser Integrity Check", from there we can find [What does the Browser Integrity Check do?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170086-What-does-the-Browser-Integrity-Check-do-):

> Cloudflare's Browser Integrity Check (BIC) is similar to Bad Behavior
>   and looks for common HTTP headers abused most commonly by spammers and
>   denies access to your page.  It will also challenge visitors that do
>   not have a user agent or a non standard user agent (also commonly used
>   by abuse bots, crawlers or visitors).

### Solution

We can change the `User-Agent` of `request` to something that should be valid *before* `request.connect();` like so (user agent copied from [User-Agent | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)):

```
request.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0");
```

The expected output is printed:

```
Ninja
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works like a charm, really appreciate it!